# How to extract trend line data from quantmod in R

Tags: r, extract, quantmod

Hi I'm doing a stats project for my school, but can't find a way to extract the data that is used to draw trend lines in `quantmod` in R

for example let's say you were to make this chart:

```
getSymbol(FXI)
chartSeries(FXI['2016-10-01::2017-01-10'])
addBBands()
```

How would I store the data points that make up the BBand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> `BBands(HLC(FXI['2016-10-01::2017-01-10']))`

```
> tail(BBands(HLC(FXI['2016-10-01::2017-01-10'])))
                 dn     mavg       up      pctB
2017-01-03 33.31337 35.77933 38.24530 0.3778032
2017-01-04 33.31241 35.69250 38.07259 0.4525575
2017-01-05 33.35037 35.63167 37.91296 0.5807290
2017-01-06 33.44524 35.53967 37.63409 0.5565790
2017-01-09 33.57770 35.44983 37.32196 0.5997525
2017-01-10 33.70263 35.39333 37.08403 0.7641903
```